# C - libxml2 - Updating XML element values and attributes

Tags: c, libxml2

I am trying to update an XML document using C and the libxml2 library.
I would like to selectively based on some configured values update an XML element and/or an attribute.

It looks like I can use `xmlSetProp` to do update an XML attribute but I can't see how I can use this to update an XML element value. It seems that when using `xmlSetProp` it adds a new attribute but think I can get round this by removing the attribute first.

Please can anybody tell me how I can use the libxml2 library to update an element. To give some context I would like to be able to handle the following XML and update the values:

```
<person sex="female">
  <firstname>Anna</firstname>
  <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</person>
```

So it seems as though I can update the sex attribute using `xmlSetProp` but how would I update the value of firstname?

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

After your guys help I wrote what I needed (below) and hope that it will benefit somebody else.

Thanks

```
xmlXPathObjectPtr GetNodeSet(const xmlDocPtr pDoc, xmlChar* pszXPath)
{
    static const char szFctName[]= __FUNCTION__;
    xmlXPathContextPtr pContext = NULL;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr pResult = NULL;

    Debug("%s '%s'\n", szFctName, pszXPath);

    pContext = xmlXPathNewContext(pDoc);
    if (pContext == NULL) 
    {
        Debug("Error in xmlXPathNewContext pContext is NULL\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    pResult = xmlXPathEvalExpression(pszXPath, pContext);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(pContext);
    if (pResult == NULL) 
    {
        Debug("Error in xmlXPathEvalExpression pResult is NULL\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(pResult->nodesetval))
    {
        xmlXPathFreeObject(pResult);
        Debug("No results found\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return pResult;
}

xmlDocPtr GetXMLDoc(char* pszXMLFilename)
{
    static const char szFctName[]= __FUNCTION__;
    xmlDocPtr pDoc = xmlParseFile(pszXMLFilename);

    Debug("%s '%s'\n", szFctName, pszXMLFilename);

    if (pDoc == NULL )
    {
        Debug("Document: '%s' not parsed successfully. \n", pszXMLFilename);
        return NULL;
    }

    return pDoc;
}

// Some code below (extracted and modified so won't compile purely for example) that is used to update the XML

// xmllib vars
xmlNodePtr pNode = NULL;
xmlDocPtr pDoc = NULL;
xmlNodeSetPtr pNodeSet = NULL;
xmlXPathObjectPtr pResult = NULL;


// Get the XML doc
pDoc = GetXMLDoc(pszXMLFilename);

// Using XPath to navigate to element.
pResult = GetNodeSet(pDoc, "/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='KeyToSearchFor']");


if (pResult && pResult->nodesetval)
{
    pNodeSet = pResult->nodesetval;
    for (iNodeSetValue = 0; iNodeSetValue < pNodeSet->nodeNr; iNodeSetValue++) 
    {
        if (pNodeSet->nodeTab)
        {
            pNode = pNodeSet->nodeTab[iNodeSetValue];

            if (pNode)
            {
                if (ItsAnElement /*I configured this*/)
                {
                    xmlNodeSetContent(pNode, szNewXMLValue);
                }
                else if (ItsAnAttribute /*I configured this*/)
                {
                    if (xmlGetProp(pNode, XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE_VALUE_NAME))
                    {
                        xmlSetProp(pNode, BAD_CAST XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE_VALUE_NAME, szNewXMLValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug("%s Couldn't find XML property value for: '%s'\n", szFctName, pParams[iTag].szXMLTagXPathValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// We're about to save our changes. Backup the file first and only update if this succeeds
if (BackupXMLFile(pszXMLFilename))
{
    // Returns: The number of bytes written or -1 in case of failure.
    if (xmlSaveFileEnc(pszXMLFilename, pDoc, "utf-8") >= 0)
    {
        iStatus = E_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug("%s xmlSaveFileEnc failed\n", szFctName);
    }
}
else
{
    iStatus = E_ERR;
}

xmlFreeDoc(pDoc);
```

Comment: Can you post code to see what have you done so far? It's hard to help by just "Please can anybody tell me how I can use the libxml2 library to update an element.", because the correct awnser will be **rtfm**.

Comment: Hi, I really don't want anybody to write the code for me. I would like to know whether xmlSetProp can be used to update an element value as it doesn't seem to work for me, or is it purely for attributes? 

If xmlSetProp cannot be used to set element values then is there another function that can be used to do so? I have read the manual and couldn't see anything other than xmlSetProp.

Thanks

Comment: [xmlNodeSetContent](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeSetContent)? You need to navigate to the actual node (ie. `firstname` and `lastname`).

Comment: That does the trick thank you so much. I'm going to complete my solution and then post my code in the hope that it will benefit somebody else! Do you want to set that as the answer so that i can accept it? Thanks again

Comment: To answer an earlier question, yes xmlSetProp is used for attributes, and can be used to update.  Because only one copy of a given attribute can exist on a given element, calling xmlSetProp on an element where the attribute already exists will overwrite the current value.

Comment: Thanks Jason i've now done all that I need to. I'm going to post it on here now.